# Responsive footer design - wrapping footer items

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, footer

I am trying to write a responsive footer. The footer items are separated by vertical bar (|). When we decrease the screen size, the footer items are wrapping to second line. Vertical bar (|) needs to be only between the footer items. Also facebook logo needs to be on the same line with the footer items for bigger screen sizes and on the center for smaller screen sizes. I used `float:right` but now they wrap from the beginning. How can I make them wrap from the end and hide vertical bar (|) if it is not between the footer items?

Here is my source code: https://jsfiddle.net/6kcdvteo/

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
}

.text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 2rem 2rem;
  color: #666666;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 2rem;
  background-color: #303741;
  color: white;
}

.footer_company {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.footer_links {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  background-color: #303741;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
}

.footer_links_span span {
  background-color: #303741;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  float: right;
}

img {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

.img {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac cursus felis, ut egestas lacus. Sed nec elementum ipsum. Morbi metus est, venenatis at libero pharetra, suscipit posuere dolor. Proin a auctor nulla, sed tincidunt tellus. Nullam bibendum
    luctus elit, sed porttitor lectus varius in. Cras venenatis rutrum urna at ultrices. Sed in luctus ligula.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <span class="footer_company">© My Company Name</span>
</div>

<div class="footer_links">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124010.png">
  </div>
  <div class="footer_links_span">
    <span>Sed metus</span>
    <span>|</span>
    <span>Aenean ultricies</span>
    <span>|</span>
    <span>Praesent vitae</span>
    <span>|</span>
    <span>Donec auctor</span>
    <span>|</span>
    <span>Vestibulum lobortis</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no CSS property that will do this. I would suggest using media queries to adjust as needed

Comment: Also the pipe in a span is less than optimal. A better option is a right border or a pseudo element

Comment: Are you open with using bootstrap? It'd make this quick and easier

Comment: It needs to be without Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your question you can use this

```
<div class="footer_links">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124010.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="footer_links_span">
    <span><b>|</b> Sed metus</span>
    <span><b>|</b> Aenean ultricies</span>
    <span><b>|</b> Praesent vitae</span>
    <span><b>|</b> Donec auctor</span>
    <span><b>|</b> Vestibulum lobortis <b>|</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this css

```
/* container */
.footer_links {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  background-color: #303741;
  color: white;
}
/* clearfix floats */
.footer_links::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
/* facebook img */
.img {
  float: left;
}
.img img {
  width: 3rem;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
/* links */
.footer_links_span {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 3.5rem);
  text-align: right;
}
.footer_links_span span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #303741;
}
.footer_links b {
  padding: 0 0.2rem;
  font-weight: inherit;
}
.footer_links_span span:first-child b {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.footer_links_span span:last-child b {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Maybe it will help you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! How can the facebook logo and footer items be on the same row as shown in the pictures?

Comment: In your html layout it is not possible to horizontal align the company name with the facebook icon. For the same reason the company name cannot pushed below the facebook icon.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, but it's Bootstrap :) All your responsive screenshotes are implemented in this code. No extra css for the layout required.

EDIT: The included style is for the width of the links block and for hiding the pipe symbool on small screens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
#footerSocial img { width: 3rem; margin-bottom: 0.5rem; }
#footerLinks > div { max-width: 350px; margin: auto; }
#footerLinks .dv { font-weight: inherit; display: none; }
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  #footerSocial img { margin-bottom: 0; }
  #footerLinks > div { max-width: none; padding-left: 100px; }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #footerLinks > div { padding-left: 0; }
  #footerLinks .dv { display: inline; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid bg-secondary text-white">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <h1 class="mb-2">Company Name</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-12 ">
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac cursus felis, ut egestas lacus.
      Sed nec elementum ipsum. Morbi metus est, venenatis at libero pharetra, suscipit posuere dolor.
      Proin a auctor nulla, sed tincidunt tellus. Nullam bibendum luctus elit, sed porttitor lectus
      varius in. Cras venenatis rutrum urna at ultrices. Sed in luctus ligula.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="row px-2 py-3">
    <div id="footerSocial" class="col-12 col-sm-2 text-center text-sm-left">
      <img class="img-fluid bg-white" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124010.png" alt="FB">
    </div>
    <div id="footerLinks" class="col-12 col-sm-10 text-center text-sm-right">
      <div>
        &copy; Company Name<br>
        <span class="text-nowrap">Sed metus</span>
        <span class="text-nowrap">| Aenean ultricies</span>
        <span class="text-nowrap">| Praesent vitae</span>
        <span class="text-nowrap"><b class="dv">| </b>Donec auctor</span>
        <span class="text-nowrap">| Vestibulum lobortis</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When 'Vestibulum lobortis' wraps, the vertical bar between 'Praesent vitae' and 'Donec auctor' gets hidden. Also there is a vertical bar left of 'Vestibulum lobortisi'. On the other hand, isn't it possible to do without bootstrap?

Comment: Ofcourse its no problem to write this without Bootstrap but it will be a bunch of css lines to get the same result. Another thing is that Bootstrap is "cross-browser" meaning that differences between browsers are eliminated by default. You may heve a look into file bootstrap.css https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/ or findout more about the classes on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/